# How to load data into reclyerview while downloading them from post async http request

Tags: c#, android, mono

I am developing an `android` app which need's to download data(products details,images) from my `server` using `httpclient` the problem is i need to wait until all data has finished download. i need to show data which has been `downloaded` while other are continue `downloading`.

Comment: are you using async task. Then in `onProgressUpdate()` notify the recyclerview. For better understanding, can you post your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to do pagination. It is the same thing that happens in social media feed, the content will download as you scroll down. For example, when you enter in the youtube app there is some video in your feed and then when you scroll down, it starts loading and then some new videos appear, this is called Pagination.

This is a complex approach but you can do it by reading the following articles. [Paging Android Guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/), [Video about Paging](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BE5bsyGGLf4&t=779s).

After reading these articles you can follow [this tutorial](http://androidkt.com/rest-api-pagination-paging-library/), and [here](https://github.com/Thumar/PagingWithRestAPI) is the source code of this tutorial.