# recyclview Viewholder are create all together causing scroll lag

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I need to create a screen which looks similar to Google play store screen, but need to add vertical recyclview also in between (Horizontal + vertical recycleview )

the problem is it causes a great lag when I scroll. the screen hangs for a second and gets resumed when all the view-holders are done creating!

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52257785/8383332) might be helpful.

Comment: Please provide the code you used

Answer (score 0):

- Use [Pagination with your list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26543131/6891563), load set of data. It will load your data quickly at start, and will occupy less memory.
- Set a [view pool to inner RecyclerView](https://proandroiddev.com/optimizing-nested-recyclerview-a9b7830a4ba7). So that scrolling does not lag.

Answer (score 0):

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/hsv"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:measureAllChildren="false"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

<-- you child view xml code and set recyclerview scroll vertical-->

<HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

reduce the size or quality of images , i think your images in one of recycler view is too large , that's why recycler view getting lazy.